# In opencart, how to get the url of the side store

Tags: opencart

I created another store in opencart, how can I get the url of the other store in controller?

Thanks,Ron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url will be which you put at the creation of the store in Store Url Field 
checkout this tutorial.

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-multi-store-setup-using-opencart--cms-22261

To get all store list at  controller

```
$this->load->model('setting/store');

$results = $this->model_setting_store->getStores();
```

the results will contain the stores information with id, name, url

Comment: I mean how can I get the url in php? any api I can use?

Comment: What do you want to accomplish exactly ?

Comment: I need to present a new page, in the page, I need to have links which will direct user to certain stores. That's why I need to get the url for each store in php.

Comment: Sorry I have not read your question properly Will you please say me why do you want to get it in another controller.

Comment: You have the built in module called store for this

Comment: which version do you use of opencart?

Comment: The latest one 2.0.1.1

Comment: Ok do you want this to do only by controller and not by built in module?

Comment: By customised controller

Comment: Ok i will come back within some minutes.